# how to use yum install the rpms listed in redhat/el6/x86_64/

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum

some rpm package could be found here, 
http://dl.marmotte.net/rpms/redhat/el6/x86_64/

like `rubygem-bundler-1.0.15-1.el6.noarch.rpm`, `rubygem-thor-0.14.6-1.el6.noarch.rpm`,

my question is how can I just use `yum install rubygem-bundler` to install these packages, what's the yum repo?

what can I add to `/etc/yum.repo.d/`

I am using amazon linux in AWS.

Comment: Using rpms from a "random" source is generally a *very* bad idea. If all you want is rubygem-bundler then I believe that's available in the CentOS software collections for [1.9](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/ruby193/) and [2.2.2](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-ruby22/).

Comment: yes, I have switched to the own yum repo of my company. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's simple, just create a file named marmatte.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d, and content is as below:

```
[marmotte]
name=marmotte
baseurl=http://dl.marmotte.net/rpms/redhat/el6/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

After saving it, run `yum makecache`.

Comment: ="The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found" -- Looks like although the rpms are there, there's no repo